# refinerycms constraints breaks routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, refinerycms

i'm running rails 3.0.10 on ruby-1.8.7p352. i installed refinerycms 1.0.8 and tried to block all access to the backend for all ip's except a whitelist. i did it by editing my routes.rb to:

```
TestWhitelist::Application.routes.draw do
  match "/refinery" => redirect( "/" ), :constraints => lambda{ |req| req.remote_ip != "127.0.0.1" }
end
```

This approach works great if i try to access /refinery from another ip than 127.0.0.1. if i try to access /refinery from 127.0.0.1 i get a "No route matches /refinery".

Comment: FYI "rake routes" output is too much for a comment but it lists all routes needed for /refinery